Automating formulas
I want to make a reset button that I assign script to. The goal of the script is to set checkboxes in a range of cells (not continuous) to false. The column beside those same cells would have an if statement for the checkbox. I get an error when I run this code. In the new formula I get =IF(RangeList= TRUE, TRUE, FALSE).  RangeList should be cell f6, f7, etc.
Here is what I have for my code.
function myFunction() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Curriculum Rubric");
var rangeToReset = sheet.getRangeList(["F6:F11", "F17:F22", "F28:F32", "F38:F44", "F50:F61", "F67:F76", "F82:f90", "F96:F102"]);
var rangeToAddFormula = sheet.getRangeList(["G6:G11", "G17:G22", "G28:G32", "G38:G44", "G50:G61", "G67:G76", "G82:G90", "G97:G103"]);
rangeToAddFormula.setFormula("=IF(" + rangeToReset + "= TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)");
rangeToReset.setValue(false);
}

I'm not sure how to get specific elements, F6, F7, F8, F9, etc.

I tried building a string for the formula.  See the code line: rangeToAddFormula.setFormula(
What should have happened is that it would refill the formulas down:
=IF(F6= TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
=IF(F7= TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
etc.
What is happening is that it is putting in
=IF(RangeList= TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
How do I replace RangeList with the specific cells?

Try look at the methods in the RangeList Class

There is only RangeList.setFormula(formula), which means the formula for each range in Ranglist must be the same formula.  You are trying to create an array of formulas for each range in rangeToReset.  There is no RangeList.setFormulas() method.  The only way I can think of doing it is to create a formulas array for each range but it would have to include some formula for the ranges in between.
